# Any good examples on programming using libssl?

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, libssl

I was wondering whether someone knows any good examples of using libssl as a programming library. Its kind of annoying only digging through the code of libssl trying to make sense of it.

Comment: This question does not necessarily ask for an off-site resource, hence my reopen vote.

Answer (score 13):

You've run into the lack of documentation problem OpenSSL has. IBM DeveloperWorks does have an [article about using OpenSSL](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/l-openssl).

If you want to utilize a better documented library, you can take a look at [Mozilla NSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS).

Comment: Tanks for the hint on NSS, did not know that yet

Comment: Links are redirect to https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/linux/ ... can you update your answer with updated links?

Answer (score 3):

Just that I'm using Openssl too and think their wiki page also has some good info:
http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: yes but at the time the question came, this wiki didn't exist yet. BTW it is a WIKI then is in constant improvment.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good working example that's especially useful for iOS developers:

the [remail](https://code.google.com/p/remail-iphone/) email client uses [MailCore](http://libmailcore.com/) iOS email library wrapper, which in turn uses the multi-purpose [libetpan](http://www.etpan.org/) email library, which in turn uses [SASL](http://asg.web.cmu.edu/sasl/), an authentication layer, which in turn uses your beloved [openSSL](http://www.openssl.org/).

So if you're a believer in the learn-by-example methodology, the above gives you a lot to work with and practice on.