# Obtaining ssl certificate on windows using C++

Tags: c++, windows, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to obtain a remote server's ssl certificate on windows. One option I have found is to use openssl. The command to do that as indicated by some posts on the [internet](http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/#cert-retrieve) is:

```
openssl.exe s_client -showcerts -connect {REMOTE_SERVER_IP}:{REMOTE_SERVER_PORT}
```

This works perfectly, but my problem is that the above command has a timeout of 300 seconds. The certificate itself gets printed pretty fast and I see no reason to wait 300 seconds when I get all I want in the first few seconds. Still I think there is no way to change the timeout parameter on s_client. So I tried to figure a way to kill a process on windows after a given period of time but again had no luck there. Any ideas on how can this be done? If there is some other windows way to a obtain a remote servers ssl certificate and store it in a file this will also do the job.

EDIT: as per Bruno's request adding more information.
I am trying to create a c++ application that gets the SSL certificate of a remote server and stores it in a file for further processing. As my application already makes use of openssl.exe I either need a solution that uses openssl.exe or a standard windows command(i.e. does not require any additional libraries).

EDIT2: I have found a way to avoid the waiting in linux - just create an empty file and redirect the input of openssl s_client to it(or use pipe to pass empty input). This works on windows as well but with older versions of openssl(0.9.8l). I tried it with 0.9.8r and with 1.0.1b and redirecting the input to an empty file does not help there.

Comment: Have you tried pressing Ctrl+C or Ctrl+D?

Comment: The command is started from a program. If I run it from the command line ctrl+c does the job but this is not what I need.

Comment: So far, this looks like a SuperUser question (hence the votes to close). If you do run this from a program, please tell us how (and which language).

Comment: I have added some more information hope now it is more clear.

Comment: openssl is a library as well. A solution would be to make the C-calls into libssl from C++, to obtain the certificate. You can use s_client as an example implementation.

Comment: @mirk I reached the same conclusion after a lot of struggle with the command line tool. I will try to understand s_client and implement some minimal code that only obtains ssl certificate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a minimalistic program I created that connects to a server and prints its ssl certificate to the standard output. Hope it will help someone else to resolve similar issue:

```
#ifdef WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#else
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#endif

#include <openssl/ssl.h>    
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

static const char *host= "10.23.10.12";
static int port=443;

int tcp_connect(const char *host,int port)
{
#ifdef WIN32
   WSADATA wsaData;
   WORD version;
   int error;

   version = MAKEWORD( 2, 0 );

   error = WSAStartup( version, &wsaData );

   /* check for error */
   if ( error != 0 )
   {
       /* error occured */
       return -1;
   }

   /* check for correct version */
   if ( LOBYTE( wsaData.wVersion ) != 2 ||
        HIBYTE( wsaData.wVersion ) != 0 )
   {
       /* incorrect WinSock version */
       WSACleanup();
       return -1;
   }

   /* WinSock has been initialized */
#endif

   struct hostent *hp;
   struct sockaddr_in addr;
   int sock;

   if(!(hp=gethostbyname(host)))
      printf("Couldn't resolve host");
   memset(&addr,0,sizeof(addr));
   addr.sin_addr=*(struct in_addr*)
         hp->h_addr_list[0];
   addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
   addr.sin_port=htons(port);

   if((sock=(int)socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,
                   IPPROTO_TCP))<0)
      printf("Couldn't create socket");
   if(connect(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&addr,
              sizeof(addr))<0)
      printf("Couldn't connect socket");

   return sock;
}

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
   SSL_CTX *ctx;
   SSL *ssl;
   BIO *sbio;
   int sock;

   SSL_METHOD *meth=NULL;
   meth=SSLv23_client_method();
   OpenSSL_add_ssl_algorithms();
   SSL_load_error_strings();
   ctx=SSL_CTX_new(meth);

   /* Connect the TCP socket*/
   sock=tcp_connect(host,port);

   /* Connect the SSL socket */
   ssl=SSL_new(ctx);
   sbio=BIO_new_socket(sock,BIO_NOCLOSE);
   SSL_set_bio(ssl,sbio,sbio);

   if(SSL_connect(ssl)<=0)
     printf("SSL connect error");

   X509 *peer;
   peer=SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl);
   PEM_write_X509(stdout, peer);

   SSL_CTX_free(ctx);

   close(sock);
#ifdef WIN32
   closesocket(sock);
   WSACleanup();
#else
   close(sock);
#endif
   exit(0);
}
```

The code is modified version of the examples found [here](http://www.rtfm.com/openssl-examples/) as suggested by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009271/any-good-examples-on-programming-using-libssl).

EDIT: I kept getting the error OPENSSL_UPLINK: no OPENSSL_APPLINK on windows. After a lot of searching around the internet I found [this post](http://old.nabble.com/Problems-running-application-td3993433.html) and added this to my code:

```
extern "C" {
   #include <openssl/applink.c>
}
```

Seems this is some work around to avoid the requirement for compiler and run-time options compatibility.

Comment: can I use domain name of site for certificate extracting? (not ip address and port) f.e. "http://google.com" instead of "10.23.10.12" port=443

Comment: this code should work just fine. Notice this call: `gethostbyname(host)` it should try to resolve the hostname.

Comment: can i get "ip address" and "port" from hostent struct that returned by gethostbyname(host)?

Comment: sorry, now I understand, 443 - is https port, and host can be domain name. Thanks!

Comment: Any idea why "SSL_connect(ssl)" is failing?

Comment: How is it failing? Maybe it is better to post a separate question instead of discussing here.