# How to retrieve a certificate thumbprint in C++

Tags: c++, certificate

I am developing a C++ application, and I need to check the thumbprint of a certificate.

I found this solution [check for a specific signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072540/winverifytrust-to-check-for-a-specific-signature), using CryptQueryObject(). but I still can't find a way to retrieve the Thumprint.

In C# I can use the method [GetCertHashString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.getcerthashstring.aspx) to get the hash (which is what I need) or use the property [X509Certificate.Thumbprint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.thumbprint.aspx)

I know I need to get the hash value of the public key, but I don't know how to retrieve the public key..

How do I do that in C++? is there a method for that?

Comment: maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578716/obtaining-ssl-certificate-on-windows-using-c

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found how to do it.

you should use [CryptHashCertificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Like that:

```
DWORD* thumbPrintSize;
BYTE* thumbPrint;   
if (!CryptHashCertificate(0, hashAlg, 0,pCertContext->pbCertEncoded,
     pCertContext->cbCertEncoded, thumbPrint, thumbPrintSize)) {
        return false;
}
```

Where pCertContext is the certificate, and hashAlg is the hashing algorithm (usually sha-1)

Comment: Does it calculate or retrieve it from certificate?

Comment: @MustafaChelik It calculates the thumbprint, because the thumbprint is not stored in the certificate.

Comment: CryptHashCertificate is deprecated, however CryptHashCertificate2 is pretty similar.  However, my thumbprint doesn't seem to match the thumbprint seen using the DigitalSignature tab in properties.

Answer (score 0):

This is once again necromancing a thread, but I'd like to also point out that another approach is to use [`CertGetCertificateContextProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certgetcertificatecontextproperty) with the `CERT_HASH_PROP_ID` flag, which will return the SHA1 hash of the certificate, or calculate it using [`CryptHashCertificate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-crypthashcertificate) (presumably with SHA1 as the hashing algorithm) where it doesn't.

If you're after thumbprints in a different algorithm than SHA1 of course this probably won't be what you're after, but from everything I've seen in windows at least, SHA1 seems to be what everything still uses.

```cpp
// most current hashing algorithms top out at about 64 bytes,
// usually much less (20 bytes is very common):
byte thumb[64] = { 0 };
DWORD thumbsz = sizeof(thumb);
if (!CertGetCertificateContextProperty(pCertContext, CERT_HASH_PROP_ID, thumb, &thumbsz))
    return false;
```

I've tested the above and confirmed it matches everything I can see in `certmgr.msc`, though I am by no means a wincrypt expert so please feel free to correct me or comment below if there are good reasons not to use this approach.